# Detect an ethernet cable in WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, code-generation, ethernet

I have setup WMI code creator on my computer which I have installed from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572).

I am wondering what **Namespace and Classes(dynamic or static)** do I need to select from WMI code creator application as shown below in an image in order to get a call back in WMI when an ethernet cable is connected to computer.

- It should say something like "Ethernet cable connected" when it is connected with computer and,
- It should say something like "Ethernet cable disconnected" when it is disconnected with computer

After selecting a proper namespace and class, I will use C# code from the code creator and run it on my computer to detect network changes on computer.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't seem interested in developing your own program, just recording a macro with existing tools.  Questions about using ordinary applications belong on Super User.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am a beginner in WMI and C# so have less knowledge in it. Little bit pointer will give me a idea to develop my own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
    var q = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NetworkAdapter'");

    var hostInstanceWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\CIMV2"), q);
    hostInstanceWatcher.EventArrived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        var adapter = (ManagementBaseObject) eventArgs.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("TargetInstance");
        var status = (ushort) adapter.GetPropertyValue("NetConnectionStatus");
        switch (status)
        {
            case 2: Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                break;
            case 7: Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
                break;
        }
    };
    hostInstanceWatcher.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: [This](http://rextester.com/RMYB32053) is what I am using. Your code did work but we are missing some events meaning when I am connecting ethernet cable, it is taking some amount of time to show connected and when I am disconnecting ethernet cable, it is taking some amount of time to show disconnected. I am wondering how can I make it responsive ? Responsive meaning when I connect any ethernet cable it should display connected instantly and when disconnect any ethernet cable it should display disconnected instantly.

Comment: The polling interval is controlled by the WITHIN clause in the query: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394527(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have put 0.001 and its responsive

Comment: How much small can it go ? Can it go like 0.00001 ?

Comment: Straight from the documentation: "The polling interval is a floating-point number, and can be fractional to accept values smaller than 1 second. However, the interval should represent a number of seconds rather than an extremely small value such as 0.001, because specifying a value that is too small can cause WMI to reject the statement as not valid—due to the resource-intensive nature of polling."